# How do I get JVM Monitor CPU statistics for Java application under Eclipse?

Tags: java, performance

I've imported JVM Monitor into Eclipse (Neon) and I can't seem to get CPU monitoring to work.   What I'm doing:

1. Create Run/Debug launcher for my Java Application, w/ "stop in main"
2. Open JVM Monitor perspective and window; JVM Explorer window opens
3. Debug the app., stopping at beginning of main
4. In JVM Explorer window, [Start Monitoring].  Select CPU
5. In debugger window, set breakpoint near exit, start the application
6. Application hits breakpoint, in JVM Explorer [Stop Monitoring]

At this point, I'd expect the CPU window (various tabs) to be full of execution times, etc., but it remains completely blank.

The JVM Monitor documentation doesn't explain (to me) how to actually get CPU reports for a simple non-service Java application.  Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

you can install JVM Monitor using this link http://jvmmonitor.org/download/index.html

Comment: what is your eclipse version

Comment: I've already installed JVM Monitor.   I'm having problems **using** it under Eclipse, specifically, getting CPU statistics.   I do not find the JVM Monitor documentation helpful.   I am using Eclipse Neon v.3